# How to remove the seal in gray picture by using openCV(python)?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to remove the seal in the following gray picture by using openCV. In this case, channel split technique is not working. Can anyone give me some hints to remove this '复印无效' seal, I already tried the binarization method but result is not very good. 
[Sample ID card picture for test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXMhQ.png)

Comment: Not a good solution but simply you can remove by using color difference.

Comment: But the corresponding color value is very close to the ID number.   I think it is impossible to remove the seal without losing some digital number in the ID sequence.

Comment: I'm wondering is it possible to convert the image from RGB to HSV and remove the seal by using hsv split or mask.